# Liferay Integration with OpenAM using Active Directory

Tags: liferay, single-sign-on

I am configuring Liferay with Open AM using Active Directory as the LDAP Server.
The problem I am facing is if i configure OpenAM to authenticate using AD I get the following error in Liferay -

```
07:52:17,962 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-15][OpenSSOUtil:146] Attributes response code 500
07:52:17,962 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-15][OpenSSOAutoLogin:132] Validating user information for null null with screen name null and email address null
07:52:17,962 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-15][AutoLoginFilter:261] Current URL /web/guest/home?p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&saveLastPath=false&_58_struts_action=%2Flogin%2Flogin&p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=0&_58_redirect=%2Fc generates exception: com.liferay.portal.security.auth.AutoLoginException: java.lang.Exception: Email address is null
```

On OpenAM side there is no error.

The steps I followed are -

1. Configure AD in Liferay and enable it
2. Configure SSO in Liferay through portal-ext file
3. Enabled pass through authentication in OpenAM.

I dont see any errors in OpenAM logs. 
The only issue I see is in Liferay logs.

The following works -

1. Liferay + AD
2. Liferay + OpenAM using OpenDJ

Let me know if anyone knows what can be done to fix the issue.

Comment: Instead of Liferay OpenSSO integration use j2ee agent to map a HTTP header and use Siteminder integration.

Liferay is using an (very) old OpenSSO SDK, not OpenAM SDK.
You should create the users in Liferay

Answer (score 0):

The error you show seam to indicate that the mappping between your openAM server data and the liferay one isn't correct. Look at the properties "open.sso.screen.name.attr" and similar from your portal.

Also keep in mind that you need to activate the ldap sync on your liferay server so the User are created and Liferay can match it with openAM data.